# Перевести код в Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли перевести этот код в Jquery?

```
function copy(str){
  let tmp = document.createElement('INPUT'), focus = document.activeElement;
  tmp.value = str;
  document.body.appendChild(tmp);
  tmp.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(tmp);
  focus.focus();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let input = document.querySelector('#copycode'), bCopy = document.querySelector('#bCopy'), log = document.querySelector('#log');

  bCopy.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(input.value) {
      try {copy(input.value);
      // Тут функция будет
    } catch(e){
      // Тут функция будет
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы перевел код вот так:

```js
function copy(str) {
  var tmp = $('<input>'),
    focus = $(':focus');
  tmp.val(str);
  $('body').append(tmp);
  tmp.select()
  document.execCommand('Copy');
  tmp.remove();
  focus.focus();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = $('#copycode'),
    bCopy = $('#bCopy'),
    log = $('#log');
  bCopy.on('click', function(e) {
    if (input.val()) {
      try {
        copy(input.val());
        // Тут функция будет
      } catch (e) {
        // Тут функция будет
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="copycode" />
<button id="bCopy">Copy</button>
```

Еще можно сократить это все, убрав часть с созданием и удалением нового инпута:

```js
function copy(field, str) {
  var focus = $(':focus');
  field.select();
  document.execCommand('Copy');
  field.off('select');
  focus.focus();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = $('#copycode'),
    bCopy = $('#bCopy'),
    log = $('#log');
  bCopy.on('click', function(e) {
    if (input.val()) {
      try {
        copy(input, input.val());
        // Тут функция будет
      } catch (e) {
        // Тут функция будет
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="copycode" />
<button id="bCopy">Copy</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Учить сразу jQuery - очень плохая идея .

1. Многие задачи так же легко решить на js, как на jquery.
2. Использование jQuery, во первых, подразумевает следование некоторому набору паттернов, а во вторых, область применения jQuery ограничена работой с DOM, что ограничит ваш кругозор, если вы будете писать только на jQuery.
3. Код на jquery пишется на обычном js с вызовами методов и свойств jquery, и надо понимать тонкости js, а их не мало. Без их знания будет тяжело писать и на jQuery.
4. Как следствие пункта 3, jQuery очень тормознутый по сравнению с js. Крайне вероятно, что однажды ради быстродействия вам придётся перейти на чистый js. Например, [ваш код vs код переведенный на jq из ответа ниже](https://jsperf.com/js-vs-jq-tobuffer/1)
5. Как следствие всех предыдущих пунктов, крайне вероятно, что однажды вам придётся читать/фиксить/допиливать код на чистом js.
6. Изучив чистый js, вы легко будете использовать jquery там, где это действительно стоит делать.

Если мне всё же не удалось убедить вас попрощатся с jQuery ради js, то я могу предложить взамен гораздо более лучший фреймворк - [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) ([на русском](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150594/))

Comment: Почему именно Vanilla JS а не любой другой?

Comment: @codename0082016 Это лучший фреймворк.

Comment: Пожалуй воспользуюсь Вашим советом. Спасибо.